# Postgresql Trigger Syntax Insert or Update or Delete

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-10

I am a newbie and I want to understand:
I understand that New is only executed with Insert or Update.
The OLD ones only with Delete "If I'm not mistaken".

And what I'm trying to do is derive "If 2 values ​​are the same but different numbers" which I insert into a table and leave the default false value, I did, but "I insert" the new data, but it should be the value "OLD" of "driver".

**¿Could that request be fulfilled?**

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3675e86f848dd4d098eff6b60bf23f37)

The trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TR_DRIVER() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT number_driver, cod_driver
        FROM driver AS con
   WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM driver_tmp AS tmp
        WHERE con.number_driver<>tmp.number_driver AND con.cod_driver=tmp.cod_driver)) THEN

INSERT INTO driver_false(number_driver, cod_driver, full_name)
    VALUES (new.number_driver, new.cod_driver, new.full_name);
ELSE

INSERT INTO driver(number_driver, cod_driver, full_name, active)
    VALUES (new.number_driver, new.cod_driver, new.full_name, new.active)
ON CONFLICT (number_driver)
DO UPDATE SET
cod_driver=excluded.cod_driver,
full_name=excluded.full_name,
active=excluded.active;

END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER TR_DRIVER_TMP AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON driver_tmp
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE TR_DRIVER() ;
```

Comment: Could you restate the question in English? I don't understand. Perhaps sample data would help.

Comment: Can I insert the "driver_tmp" data into the "driver" table and update the existing ones?.
I don't understand why, the IF statement gives me the New value for the "driver_false" table. What I want to do is: Pass the previous value that exists in "driver" to "driver_false" and remove it from "driver". How can I perform that IF statement?

Example Code: 

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3675e86f848dd4d098eff6b60bf23f37

Comment: You are using an `AFTER TRIGGER`, per the link in my answer below:"The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored;"  In other words you can't make any changes to the returned row. You need a `BEFORE TRIGGER`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be testing the BEFORE, now Can I make 2 triggers under the same conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken, OLD also exists for `UPDATE` as update in Postgres is actually `INSERT/DELETE`. For the details see:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

> NEW

> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.
> OLD

> Data type RECORD; variable holding the old database row for UPDATE/DELETE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for INSERT operations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be reviewing it.